# maximum degree of a vertex in graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The $2^n$ vertices of a graph G correspond to all subsets of a set of size $n$, for $n>= 6$. Two vertices of G are adjacent if and only if the corresponding subsets intersect in exactly two elements. Then what is the maximum degree of a vertex in G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$, and let $\wp([n])$ be the vertex set of $G$. Suppose that $V\subseteq[n]$ has cardinality $k\ge 2$; what is the degree of $V$ in terms of $k$ and $n$? Note that any $2$-element subset of $V$ can be combined with any subset of $[n]\setminus V$ (unless $k=2$, in which case you can’t use the empty subset of $[n]\setminus V$). What value of $k$ maximizes this number? (Bear in mind that $n\ge 6$.)

**Added:** $V$ has $\binom{k}2$ $2$-element subsets that can be its intersection with adjacent vertices. If $k>2$, each of those can be combined with any of the $2^{n-k}$ subsets of $[n]\setminus V$ to make a vertex adjacent to $V$ in $G$, so $\deg_G(V)=\binom{k}22^{n-k}$. If $k=2$, $V$ has only one $2$-element subset, and combining it with the empty subset of $[n]\setminus V$ just gives us the vertex $V$ back again, so $V$ has a maximum of $2^{n-2}-1$ neighbors, one for each **non-empty** subset of $[n]\setminus V$. Given that $n\ge 6$, what value of $k$ maximizes $\deg_G(V)$, and what is that maximum? (There may be more than one value of $k$ that works.)

Comment: No other vertex of G has more $2$-element subsets than $[n]$. And $[n]$ has $nC2$ subsets. so is this the answer?

Comment: @gaathiyo: Let me revise that hint: everything that you’ve said is right, but I was being stupid about the best way to get maximum degree, and we can do better.

Comment: for any vertex $V$ has cardinality $k=2$, will have maximum number of degree (Not sure). And its degree will be "summation of (n-2)C0 to (n-2)C(n-2). Please help. I am not sure.

Comment: @gaathiyo: I’ve added a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the answer. So can we say that in general that it will always maximize the no. of degrees for floor(n/2)?

Comment: @gaathiyo: That’s not what I get: I get a maximum at $k=3$ and $k=4$, the maximum being $3\cdot2^{n-3}$. As $k$ increases, the $\binom{k}2$ factor increases quadratically, but the other factor decreases exponentially, so for large enough $k$ (which seems to be $k\ge 4$) the product decreases.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8244/discussion-between-gaathiyo-and-brian-m-scott)